# Status Bar в iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

Наверняка, если вы уже сталкивались с iOS 7, вы понимаете, о чем идет речь:

В iOS7 похоже изменилась система отсчета у view-объектов, и если запустить проект, работающий нормально в iOS <= 6.1, в iOS 7, его контент будет выводиться поверх прямо статус бара (на всякий случай "статус бар" - это где часы, вай-фай, моб. оператор...), а внизу будет пустая полоса 20px. То есть как будто бы views стали отсчитываться с (0, 0) экрана, а не как раньше с (0, 20).

На SO на этот счет внятных ответов я не нашел, так как там все вопросы про iOS 7 минусуют и закрывают, и говорят, что нужно идти на Apple forums. Единственное, что я нашел это [вот этот неубедительный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17121958/598057), который опять же ссылаясь на Apple forums, утверждает, что прежнее поведение отсчета views с 20 пикселей является *"an old bug"* и что нынешнее поведение *"is actually a fix"*. На самих форумах Apple тоже внятной информации с точным решением я пока не нашел.

Я прочитал `iOS7 UI Transition guide`, и видел, что

> *In iOS 7, view controllers use full-screen layout.*

но мне интересно (внимание, вопрос!), **можно ли с помощью кода сохранить старое поведение предыдущих версий iOS и в версии iOS 7.0**? Изменение разных параметров, которые Apple описывает в этом гайде, не дало мне нужного, даже приблизительно, результата.

Примечание: я имею в виду поведение проектов, написанных руками, без использования Storyboards.

Comment: На ответ не тянет ибо костыли, потому напишу коментом. Из того что пробовал я это либо сдвигать весь контроллер при заргрузке\показе, либо все упаковывать в нафигейшнконтроллер - они обрабатываются корректно (но у них теперь tintColor стал называться barTintColor, а старое свойство теперь отвечает за другое, translucent стал по умолчанию YES И все это без отражения в апи дифф). Разделение по осям стандартное - в рантайме через if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))...else (цельнотянутая група макросов из http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Comment: @Stanislaw, думаю все же стоит дождаться появления официальной документации по новой версии ОС, не думаю что такое несовпадение будет решаться дополнительными усилиями. Скорее всего система сама будет хендлить отсутствие или наличие фулл-скрин режима

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю, просто решил проверить, может быть оно уже решается как-то на приличном уровне. Что касается дополнительных усилий, то судя по `iOS7 UI Transition guide` iOS7 легко идет на разного рода breaking changes, что означает, что ей же самой и придется заниматься тем, чтобы внедрять всякие workarounds для всего семейства осей до iOS7.

Comment: @aknew, спасибо за ответ. У меня все завернуто в navigation controller, но все равно корректно скрины не обрабатываются. Что касается сдвигов - я прямо сейчас пытаюсь делать то же. Хочу убедиться в том, что существует приличный, наименее костыльный способ это сделать.

Comment: @AlexThumb мне бы вашу уверенность, весь мой опыт работы с айосью(я с ней имею дело начиная с перехода с 2 на 3, хотя и с небольшим перерывом как раз на тройке)говорит о том, что это просто оставят на откуп разрабам, самый свежий пример - автолейауты в 6.0, разве эппл сделал что-то для упрощения или хотя бы чтобы приложение не падало? А так нововведения в 7.0 ввели мягко говоря по идиотски-одно то что переколбасили половину энумов чего стоит. У нас несколько проектов не собиралось т.к. часть энумов из UIKit заменили на энумы из настольного, а мы собирали с -Werror и огребли несоотвествие типо

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich я не костыльный способ не нашел, но может плохо искал, если найдете-отпишите плиз. А вообще фраза про старую ошибку похожа на правду - я как-то делал принтскрин штатными средстваи, так если делать его для всего окна, получаем сверху серую полоску т.к. статус бар просто отрисовывается сверху (в отдельном окне) и ему оставляют место смещая все UIView в UIWindow на 20 поинтов, при этом само UIWindow всегда занимает весь экран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в своё время нашёл решение для своего вопроса, и так и не собрался оформить его здесь в виде ответа. Не очень удобное, но работающее самым надёжным из всех возможных образом.

Кратко: я завернул view-иерархию каждого контроллера в ещё один UIView *compatibilityContainerView, который и выполнял необходимое мне позиционирование. В одной из ссылок на эту тему: [Wrestling with Status Bars and Navigation Bars on iOS 7](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7) этот способ описан под цифрой 9.

---

Теперь же похоже это постепенно становится неактуальным, так как Apple говорит нам в принудительном порядке адаптировать приложения под iOS 7: [С 1 февраля 2014 все новые приложения должны быть адаптированы под iOS7](http://www.siliconrus.com/2013/12/ios7-2014-feb/).

Comment: не согласен что неактуально - адаптировать означает всего лишь чтобы приложения выглядили на iOs 7 как родные, но это ни разу не отменяет возможности их запуска в более ранней оси.

По сабжу - я на стековерфлоу видел шестой пункт из того же списка и мне он показался самым многообещающим, но поиграться руки так и не дошли. А 9 это все тотже костыль с перемещением, до которого ИМХО все додумались

Comment: @aknew, я поэтому и пишу, что _постепенно_ становится. А по поводу 6 пункта - я пробовал ещё тогда, 2-3 месяца назад - у меня не получилось добиться хорошего результата. Если кто-то сюда напишет мега-ответ, буду рад ознакомиться с лучшим решением.